# How to free up the memory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory-management, html5-canvas

I'm working with canvas and its ImageData object which contains a huge amount of data (millions of integers). So working with a few arrays already takes a lot of memory (up to 300MB). Is there a way to free up the memory of some array when it's unnecessary? I'm trying to assign `undefined` to that variable. Is it right?

Comment: You can't manage memory allocation in Javascript or call the garbage collector.

Comment: I believe that's all you can do. The rest is up to the garbage collector.

Comment: So all that I can do is to use as less arrays as possible?

Comment: you could assign `null` instead of `undefined`

Comment: It may be worth noting that since you can pass bounds to getImageData, you don't necessarily have to work on the entire image data array at once.  Depending on what you're doing, it may consume less peak memory to work on the image in chunks, so that garbage collection can work between the chunks.

Comment: You can free up memory in an array by setting the length to 0. So you could do myArray.length=0; myArray = null;

Comment: @mbokil why is it better than `myArray = null`?

Comment: @haynar in some ways the length=0 is better since you can free up memory in the array and later use it again, say, pushing objects onto the array. Setting it to null would remove the type of object it points to being array so later on you would have to do myArray = [] if you wanted to use it.

Comment: @mbokil How can you "free up memory in the array and later use it again"? How that works?

Comment: Would using a new Map(); instead of and variable clear the garbage when we call myMap.clear(); ?

Comment: @inux it should, since `Map.prototype.clear()` removes all elements from the map and they can not be accessed anymore.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

If the variable persists (e.g. it's global or part of some persistent data structure) and the data it points to is large and you want that data to be eligible for garbage collection, then you are correct to assign something small to that variable.  `undefined` or `null` or `""` will all work.  What you're doing is clearing the reference to the large data so that it will be eligible for garbage collection.  If nothing else in your javascript has a reference to that data, then it can be freed by the garbage collector.  If anything else has a reference to it, then it cannot be freed.

For example, if you had a 10,000 element array held in a global variable:

```
var largeDataArray = new Array(10000);
```

And, you had filled most elements with data, then you could allow that memory to be eligible for garbage collection by assigning it some other value like:

```
largeDataArray = null;
```

or if you still want it to be an array:

```
largeDataArray = [];
```

Note: variables that themselves go out of scope (like local variables in functions that aren't part of a lasting closure) or variables in objects that themselves go out of scope do not have to be manually cleared.  When they go out of scope or when the parent object is deleted, the data contained within will also be eligible for garbage collection.

So, the clearing of a variable only needs to be done when you explicitly want to free data that is held in a long lasting variable and it's usually only relevant to worry about this when the data is large or you have a lot of them that add up to multiple megabytes of data (memory use is of higher concern at lower levels on smartphones than in desktop browsers).

Comment: thx for great answer :) it's gonna be candidate to be marked as solution if no more new facts will be highlighted

Comment: Well said (+1). Another way to clean up variable references: `delete`.

Comment: is there a `delete` method in js?

Comment: There is a `delete` in javascript, but it's mostly for deleting properties from objects, not like delete works in C++.  You can read all about delete [here](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

Comment: @haynar it's an operator, not a method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Another good reference on `delete`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator.

Comment: @jfriend00 @МДГГ yes `delete` works only with the properties, so I think to modify my code to have all data arrays as properties in one global object. what do you think?

Comment: @haynar - you make make it a property and use `delete` or you can just set the variable you have now to null.

Comment: I think it's better to not modify anything and just set `null` variables :)

Comment: largeDataArray.length = 0 deletes all elements. largeDataArray = [] changes reference of largeDataArray does not delete original array so doing something like arrayA = [0, 1, 2]; arrayB = arrayA; arrayA = []; console.log(arrayA, arrayB) => [], [0,1,2]

Comment: @AdamMichalski - The point here is that reassigning anything to `largeDataArray` allows the previous array to be eligible for garbage collection (if there are no other references to it).  Yes, you could also set `.length` to zero depending upon your circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript has automatic memory management. Memory containing objects which are no longer referenced will be eligible for garbage collection, unless you have a memory leak. **There is generally no need to manually assign `undefined` to variables.**

If your program is using too much memory, you should **shrink** the arrays to get rid of elements you no longer need. See [`Array.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), [`Array.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), and [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: This is wrong that there is generally no need to manually assign undefined to variables.  If you want the memory consumed by a large variable to be freed and that variable is long lasting (e.g. global or part of some object that persists), then one way to let the memory be freed is to reassign the variable something that is very small so the large data that was being used will no longer have any references to it and can be garbage collected.  I didn't downvote yet, but I'm thinking about it because this post is misleading in some cases and wrong in others.

Comment: Relying too much on the garbage collector is also not advised. In case of memory shortage the garbage collectors aggressively try to free up memory. Even though the garbage collectors have come a long way but such aggressive garbage collection can hit your performance.