# jQuery closures garbage collector

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

Before asking I read this question:

[How to free up the memory in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467350/how-to-free-up-the-memory-in-javascript)

When your variable data is large and you want that data to be eligible for garbage collection, then you are correct to assign something small to that variable, like `undefined` or `null` or `""`. But it only make sense when the variable persists (e.g. it's global or part of some persistent data structure) as stated in previous question.

Then I made a test request like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('http://localhost/small-data', function(r) {
       r = null;
    },'json');
}, 1000);
```

In my example, my URL (at localhost) will output only `5KB`;

jQuery will parse the response `r` as JSON and I create a loop with `setInterval` that's not doing anything else and after a few hours Firefox will have more than `1GB` at the task manager.

It doesn't make sense. FF never frees memory. Does this example code have a memory leak?

Comment: Just in Firefox, or other browsers too? If I recall, jQuery's AJAX functions have a history of being leaky. what version are you using? It's doubtful that the `r` parameter is the issue.

Comment: @amnotiam I have tested at Firefox 20.0.1 and jquery-1.8.2.min.js - I put the example JSON at http://pastebin.com/YWJxa7Pv if you want repeat my test.

Comment: I'm running this with the same version of jQuery on Firefox 20 on Linux, and the garbage seems to be collected as expected so far. Is there any other code that you're running?

Comment: Firefox is known to manage good in memory. Chrome is a catastrophe