# ExtJS Heap Snapshots.. When Should I start worrying?

Tags: javascript, memory, extjs, memory-leaks

I wanted to identify memory leaks in my web app (Extjs 4.1 + PHP + OpenLayers) using Chrome DevTools. I took a heap snapshots before and after navigating around my app. As you see below, the initial size was 19.5 MB. Then after using some functionalities it grows up to 27.9 MB. I left the app open then came back after couple of hours and took another heap snapshot, it was 28 MB. Then I refreshed the page and it went back to be 19 MB again. Does this mean that these functionalities are eating a lot of machine memory and I should be worried?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 19 MB baseline shows that you are using a library that keeps a lot of objects in memory (if I go to the Sencha docs and navigate a few places I see their page is also consuming ~19mb of memory, so you seem to be about on-par with them).

Your app seems to also load some large objects into memory (the extra 10 MB you get while using your app - assuming no refresh here), but since you refreshed the page and the footprint went down to the baseline of ~19 MB it appears that you do not have any memory leaks in Chrome. However, you may not be releasing unused objects as you navigate within your site. You can release memory by setting objects to null ([How to free up the memory in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467350/how-to-free-up-the-memory-in-javascript)) after you are done with them.

No memory leak in Chrome does not mean no memory leak in IE or other browsers.

The extra 0.1 MB of memory consumed while sitting on the page for a few hours might be something to look into - especially if your end users will be leaving the page up for long periods of time and/or are running on low powered machines or mobile devices. However, to put it in perspective, my machine has eight GB of memory, so I'd have to keep this page up for quite a long time to have any adverse impact.

This is a detailed description of memory lifecycle management from mdn that you might find useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Real_life_example

(I wouldn't worry about 30 mb heap for most users ;)