# Three js children length

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created a three js object and added some children to it. then i changed the length of children to 0. then the objects have gone out of screen. Will that make the objects fully removed from the screen and memory?

```
var balls = new THREE.Object3D();  // parent
```

for  creating childrens

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0f0ff0, shininess: 50, transparent: true, opacity: 1});
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
sphere.position.x = scale('some random value');
sphere.position.y = scale('some random value');
balls.add(sphere);
```

above steps repeated for more spheres

then in the console i wrote

```
balls.children = [];
```

this removes all the spheres from the scene. Will that removes all the sphere objects from the memory also??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8467563/3264799 You are doing it "right", since you want that to be garbage collected. However, the Three.js-way would be to remove each element from the scene through the `scene.remove( child )` method. It would be a good practice to do it the way Three.js wants it, since it is responsible for creating and controlling the elements anyway. Sometimes libraries might get confused if they have some private variables that contain information about stuff, but then that stuff gets suddenly deleted, it breaks the system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you have an array and then set `array.length = 0;` all the elements of the array will be deleted. When you type `array.length = 2`, all elements other than the first two elements will be deleted.
Javascript has a function called `slice()` which does a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way for deleting a child is calling remove(child) from its parent, and then use dispose() on children's material and geometry.

In your code:

```
var balls = new THREE.Object3D();  // parent

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0f0ff0, shininess: 50, transparent: true, opacity: 1});
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
sphere.position.x = scale('some random value');
sphere.position.y = scale('some random value');
balls.add(sphere);

// Do some work

balls.remove(sphere);
geometry.dispose();
material.dispose();
```

Dispose the material/geometry only when it is not used by other Mesh anymore.

From [THREE.Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D) at *remove(object, ...)*:

> "Removes object as child of this object. An arbitrary number of objects may be removed."

From [THREE.Geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry) at *dispose()*:

> "Don't forget to call this method when you remove a geometry because it can cause memory leaks."

From [THREE.Material](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material) at *dispose()*:

> "This disposes the material. Textures of a material don't get disposed. These needs to be disposed by Texture."

If you use [textures](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture), you must dispose these too.

(THREE.js r85).