# assigning different value to javascript arrays created using new

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I have written a webpage that helps in solving wordle using javascript.
It is similar to https://tryhardguides.com/wordle-solver/.
The difference is that my webpage can be run offline as all 2308 solutions and 12974 allowed guesses are saved in different array variables, also I allow multi letter input for yellow boxes.

Anyway, that was just a little explanation about purpose of my code.

My question for this thread is as follows:

1. I create global variable greenarray that holds a single letter guess for each position using

```js
var greenarray=new Array(5).fill(0);
```

I am adding a reset button in it, so what would be the best way to fill `greenarray` with zeroes again? I believe that `greenarray=new Array(5).fill(0);` would leak 5 values I allocated in memory. Is that right? If so, then what is the appropriate way?

2. I am using another global variable yellowarray that holds multiple letter guesses for each position using

```js
yarr  = new Array(5);                                                                                                      
for (var i = 0; i < yarr.length; i++) 
{
    yarr[i] = [];
}
```

Here I am pushing and popping letters to particular `yarr[i]` depending on user added characters or deleted previous ones to i'th position.

Here I think that resetting can be done by simply doing `yarr[i]=[]` as suggested at [How to free up the memory in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467350/how-to-free-up-the-memory-in-javascript). Is that ok?

3. Last thing, if somebody reloads the page then is memory allocated via `new` freed automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Why construct a new array? If you want to fill it with zeros again just do `greenarray.fill(0)` -- also, you won't have a memory leak from reconstructing an array of numbers, this is javascript

Comment: ok . i added third part to question . can you post it as answer with comment for each part ?